# Paypal Integration - Add to cart button

Tags: php, mysql, html, paypal

I'm making an ecommerce site and I'm currently trying to implement my cart using Paypal.

I have a table of products created via the following code:

```
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
    <td>£<?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['stockLevel'] ?></td>
    <td><!--Add to cart button will go here--></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

This is going through my table and getting the component details and showing them through a table. Now with Paypal add to cart buttons you have to enter the details of a product manually (e.g. Enter the products name, price etc) and then Paypal generates it for you on its site so you can just copy/paste the HTML. I was wondering if there was a way of doing what I am doing now whereby I am populating the table via the database, but also creating a Paypal button which links to that component at the same time so I wouldn't have to create a seperate button for each component?

Comment: As you can probably imagine: yes it is. Please do your homework first and look this up in the developer documentation of paypal.

Comment: Yes it is to what? I've been looking at the documentation for an hour and can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering how I did it:

You simply do `<?php echo $row['name'] ?>` where 'name' is your particular column. All I was missing was an echo.

Answer (score 0):

paypal offer add to cart button in website with complete coading...Check Link Below.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/web-accept-to-sc-button-outside

Comment: The thing I am having an issue with is to create the button for each product without having to do it manually. I.e. I have done 

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=<?$row['name']?>">'
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<? $row['price']?>">

However when I click 'Add to Cart' on a particular component it comes up in the basket with no information and no price set.

Comment: You will have to have some JavaScript code do exactly what the instructions provided by Paypal in the link cgvector provided tell you to do manually.

Comment: Hi Gilbert, I can't find any Javascript to do this type of task, is there somewhere you know where I could find it?